# Show $S_3$ is the semi-direct product of $A_3$ by $H=\{(1),(12)\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, semidirect-product

> Show $S_3$ is the semi-direct product of $A_3$ by $H=\{(1),(12)\}$

How would you prove such a question? Showing $H \cap N = \{id\}$ is fine, where $N=A_3$, but how would I show that $A_3H=G$ for semi-direct products?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $N$? ${}$

Comment: A3, normal subgroup of S3

Comment: Then what do you mean by $A_3N=S_3$?

Comment: typo, meant A3H

Comment: *Hint:* $$A_3\cong\langle(123)\rangle.$$

Comment: A3 is cyclic generated by 123?

Comment: @Jos There is only one group of 3 elements (Up to isomorphism)

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think I get it now, thank you Alan and Shaun

Comment: Hint: $A_3 H$ strictly contains $A_3$, and $A_3$ is a subgroup of index 2...